# JQUERY button return to index element

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My problem is this, I have a page where there is a button used to change the state of a table.
What is happening is that if the page is scrolled and I click the button that is below, it will update the status page and will rise. What I want is that when the state changed it remains the place where the button was clicked.

**OPEN SHADOW:**

```
 $(".table-change-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = this.rel;
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (result) {
            $("#" + div).html(result);
            $("#" + div).dialog({ width: 500, height: 200, modal: true });
        });
    });
```

**VIEW**:

```
<td class="table-comand">
        <a href="@Url.Action("AlterarSituacao", ViewBag.Routes)" title="Atualizar Situação"      class="table-change-link" id="situacao" rel="DivAtualizaSituacao"></a>
        <div id="DivAtualizaSituacao"></div>
    </td>
```

**CONTROLLER:**
this is a action of request

```
  public ActionResult AlterarSituacao(int page=1)
        {
            CreateRouteValuesForFilters();
            routes.Add("page", page);
            ViewBag.Routes = routes;

            ViewBag.IdSituacaoDocumentoLOV = new SelectList(this.repository.GetAllSituacao().ToList(), "IdSituacaoDocumento", "NomeSituacao");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AlterarSituacao(int IdSituacaoDocumento, int id, int page = 1)
        {
            CreateRouteValuesForFilters();
            routes.Add("page", page);
            ViewBag.Routes = routes;

            this.repository.AlteraSituacaoDocumento(id, IdSituacaoDocumento);
            this.repository.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index",routes);
        }
```

How make this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you'll need to add a little more code to show what the jquery does on returning from the `AlterarSituacao` `action`. my guess is that after the ajax call, it returns a `partialview` and pre-pends the updated `<td>` element and removes the old one- as i said, guesswork until more code present

**[update]** to show scrolling to bring `<td>` into view based on id:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#item.IdSolicitacao').offset().top,
    scrollLeft: $('#item.IdSolicitacao').offset().left
}, 'slow');
```

obviously, you should be able to *grab* the `<td>` id as a variable from your routine, rather than the hardcoded example above.

Comment: José, post your ajax code and I think we'll be off to the races.. (i.e. update the original post)

Comment: José, it sounds then like it's not using ajax, and instead, using a full redirecttoaction on post. unless you send back some sort of id, then i'm afraid this won't be possible as the page has no longer got any context on the initiating action. you really need to make the question more comprehensive as we're kinda hacking our way thro until the next dead end in understanding is exposed